# PHP see only 20 uploading files at a time

Tags: php, file, upload

When I try to upload more than 20 files at a time, then the web server see only first 20. Any other files are just ignored. What is the problem?

Simple code to try:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
if($_FILES){
    print_r($_FILES);
}
else{
    for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
    {
        echo '<input type="file" name="file'.$i.'"><br/>';
    }
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

`print_r()` output:

```
Array ( [file0] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpD42.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file1] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpD52.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file2] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpD73.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file3] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpD83.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file4] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpD94.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file5] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpDB4.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file6] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpDC5.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file7] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpDE5.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file8] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpDF5.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file9] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpE06.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file10] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpE26.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file11] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpE37.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file12] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpE57.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file13] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpE68.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file14] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpE78.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file15] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpE98.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file16] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpEB9.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file17] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpEC9.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file18] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpEE9.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) [file19] => Array ( [name] => 39442.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => W:\tmp\phpEFA.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 274217 ) )
```

.htaccess:
php_value max_file_uploads 100  - doesn't help

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads', 100) - doesn't help
```

I just added line to php.ini on my local server :

```
max_file_uploads = 100
```

And it's helped. But I don't think that the hoster change it on client's web server. It would be very cool effect on this value without editing `php.ini`.

Comment: What does the `print_r($_FILES)` show? Can you post the full output?

Comment: Are you sure your browser does send more than 20 files at a time?

Answer (score 18):

Set the [max-file-uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) setting higher (yes, it's a 'newish' setting).

It's [PHP_INI_SYSTEM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php), so it can either be set in php.ini or webserver/apache configuration. No `.htaccess` or 'in-script' access I'm afraid.

Comment: I did. But thats allways equal 20 )

Comment: ini_set('max_file_uploads', 22);
echo ini_get('max_file_uploads');

Comment: .htaccess : php_value max_file_uploads 100    doesn't help too

Comment: It's [PHP_INI_SYSTEM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php), so it can either be set in php.ini or webserver/apache configuration. No `.htaccess` or 'in-script' access I'm afraid.

Answer (score 9):

Recently I came across the same issue, but unfortunately none of the above solutions worked for me. So I think I must share the worked solution here

When I was trying to upload 50+ images, the server was limiting it to 20. (I was working on a Centos Server with PHP 5.3.6)

Setting `max_file_uploads = 100` in PHP.ini file didn't help even but the number file upload limit changed to 25

On searching the numeric value 25 in the phpinfo() page, I came across a parameter suhosin.upload.max_uploads with value 25.

Setting suhosin.upload.max_uploads to 100 along with `max_file_uploads = 100` in the PHP.ini file worked, now on the server we can upload upto 100 files. (I am not sure if we have any other file where we modify the values suhosin parameters , but setting suhosin values in either php.ini OR php.d/suhosin.ini will work :) )

```
max_file_uploads = 100    
suhosin.upload.max_uploads=100
```

http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html

Comment: THANK YOU! This was the problem for me too.

Comment: For some reason my Hostinger server was ignoring my max_file_uploads and limiting to 20 files at a time when I initially set it to 1000, so I changed it to 950 and now it's working ok... weird stuff happens sometimes... +1

Answer (score 2):

There are limits as to how much PHP can post. See the [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize), [max_file_uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads), and [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) directives.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) or [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) setting limitations.

You can change them in php.ini (post_max_size should be larger than upload_max_filesize)

Answer (score 1):

You can create **php.ini** file in your website directory on hosting, and write this in it:

> max_file_uploads = 400

This is allowed way to overwrite php.ini on most hostings (but not in localhost XAMP, etc.) as far as I tried

Answer (score 1):

If you run PHP as Apache module you might want to change it at virtual host level (aka `httpd.conf`). You need to remember that, being a `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` directive, you have to use *php_**admin**_value* (regular *php_value* will be ignored). Sample code could be:

```
<Location "/api">
    php_admin_value max_file_uploads 250
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: If you are working on localhost with Xampp server than open xampp control panel
click on config button than open php.ini

Step 2: find **max_file_uploads=20**

Step 3: Change value 20 with custom value

Step 4: Save this **php.ini** file and close

Step 5: restart your Apache server by clicking stop and than click on start wait for green color background means apache started successfully

Final test by uploading file using your code

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit set to 20 by the `max_file_uploads` configuration option.

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

There is another php.ini inside apache folder path would be /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini. Edit in thi php.ini as max_file_uploads = 500 and then restart apache. It will Work for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can set either ***.htaccess*** or ***php.ini*** files. sometimes not going to work ini_set

in **.htaccess** file. Add below lines

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 400M
php_value post_max_size 400M
php_value max_file_uploads 100
```

you have to set upload_max_filesize  & post_max_size based on number of files uploading.

example: *100 (Images) & 3MB (Per Image size) = 300MB (Total Sizes)*