# PHP/Apache is limiting the number of files that can be uploaded in one post. how increase this?

Tags: php, file-upload

**EDIT**

I tested this for size vs number and it is the numebr of files that is limiting it, not the size. I was able to upload 1 file that's bigger than all 23 files put together.

**ORIGINAL POST**
I've tested this on multiple servers and they show the same thing, the `$_FILES` array will only contain up to 15 of the uploaded files, the rest are arrays with empty values. I did a `var_dump` and got the following:

```
/** THIS IS WHAT FILES 1-15 LOOK LIKE **/
["file15"]=> array(5) {
    ["name"]=> string(14) "myimage.jpg"
    ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php5LkG6k"
    ["error"]=> int(0)
    ["size"]=> int(86267)
}

/** THIS IS WHAT FILES 16-23 LOOK LIKE **/
["file16"]=> array(5) {
    ["name"]=> string(0) ""
    ["type"]=> string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) ""
    ["error"]=> int(4)
    ["size"]=> int(0)
}
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php
try
{
    if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] === "POST" )
    {
        foreach ( $_FILES as $file )
        {
            //This isn't called until file 16
            if ( $file[ "error" ] !== 0 ) throw new Exception( "Error: " . $file[ "name" ] );

            $index = 0;
            while ( file_exists( "/var/www/wp-content/uploads/" . $index . $file[ "name" ] ) ) $index++;
            $name = "/var/www/wp-content/uploads/" . $index . $file[ "name" ];
            move_uploaded_file( $file[ "tmp_name" ], $name );
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception $e){ var_dump( $e ); }
?>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="p" value="" />
    <input type="file" name="file1" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" />
    <input type="file" name="file3" />
    <input type="file" name="file4" />
    <input type="file" name="file5" />
    <input type="file" name="file6" />
    <input type="file" name="file7" />
    <input type="file" name="file8" />
    <input type="file" name="file9" />
    <input type="file" name="file10" />
    <input type="file" name="file11" />
    <input type="file" name="file12" />
    <input type="file" name="file13" />
    <input type="file" name="file14" />
    <input type="file" name="file15" />
    <input type="file" name="file16" />
    <input type="file" name="file17" />
    <input type="file" name="file18" />
    <input type="file" name="file19" />
    <input type="file" name="file10" />
    <input type="file" name="file21" />
    <input type="file" name="file22" />
    <input type="file" name="file23" />
    <input type="file" name="file24" />
    <input type="file" name="file25" />
    <input type="file" name="file26" />
    <input type="file" name="file27" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

How do I increase the number of allowed images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: @AdrianPreuss no, it's not the size, it's the number

Comment: The same. If you upload 30 files â 500 MB, logical conclusion?

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I already tested the size and I'm able to upload 1 file of bigger size than my 23 files together. I ruled that out. I puposely chose tiny (30K each) files for my testing to rule that out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22834014/857025

Basically you need to change two fields in php.ini:

```
max_file_uploads = 100    
suhosin.upload.max_uploads = 100
```