# How to fix max_file_uploads Limit increase in Our hosted domain

Tags: php

How to fix max_file_uploads Limit increase in Our hosted domain

How to fix max_file_uploads Limit increase with php

Htaccess is not working also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP see only 20 uploading files at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083179/php-see-only-20-uploading-files-at-a-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to update the limit you have to edit hosted domain php.ini file and

find below lines in php.ini file.

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
    max_file_uploads=20(default) => change it as per you requierment.

*max_file_uploads=20 (it is default limit ) => change it as per you requierment.*

Comment: Thanks Brother for help

Answer (score 4):

If you can not access `php.ini` file then you can try this on PHP code,

```
<?php
ini_set('max_file_uploads', '50');
?>
```

Or if you can access `php.ini` file then search `max_file_uploads` and change the default value,

```
max_file_uploads=50
```

Another option is create a `.htaccess` file on your root folder(project folder) then add,

```
php_value max_file_uploads 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Use .htaccess not any php.ini & init_set

```
php_value max_file_uploads 50
```

Answer (score 0):

first check

```
phpinfo();
```

if the value of max_file_uploads is still 20 then create a file `.user.ini` on your project root and add this code

```
max_file_uploads=50
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can set either .htaccess or php.ini files.*

in **.htaccess** file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value max_file_uploads 50
```