# how to capture multi upload from postman to $_FILES of PHP

Tags: php, laravel, postman

i Have like 30 uploads using postman. on the receiving endpoint function
i tried to print_r all the uploads that were supposed to be received by PHP

```
public function capture() {

    print_r($_FILES);exit;

}
```

out of the 30 uploads only 20 got printed. There's no limit in the $_FILES super variables right? is there anyway that I can capture all 30 uploads via PHP ?

Comment: Please Check This Url
[Please Click this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185300/how-to-send-multiple-files-in-postman-restful-web-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the "20 files upload limit" problem is not imposed by the limit in the `$FILES` super global, but related to php `max_file_uploads` limit

So if you are trying to upload an array of files, you will not be able to upload more than 20 files due to max_file_uploads limit in php. ini which is `by default set to 20` . So you have to increase this limit to upload more than 20 files

For details, please visit

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

(see section on max_file_uploads)

Comment: This is a huge problem. it's prohibited to alter any server configuration especially the php.ini...what if I use ini_set at the beginning of my endpoint function to adjust the max_file_uploads. is that a viable solution for this without altering the php.ini file ?

Comment: In my understanding it is possible to use ini_set (or .htaccess) in most servers (unless the web server admin has imposed further restriction on ini_set) . Please see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300956/how-to-fix-max-file-uploads-limit-increase-in-our-hosted-domain) too